# Skip Empty cell Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a script to count a percentage of cells that has a specific value. However, when it counts the rows it does not count out the cells that are **NaN**. Basically I do not want the script to count a cell with the value **NaN** as a row. I have tried everything from `!= ""`
to `.isnan`

What im trying to do is calculating the percentage of cells that has a specific value which is not possible if the function counts the rows with **NaN** value.

**RELEVANT CODE**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(supplier_data_df, columns=['supplier keywords', 'supplier in ocr']) 

total_suppliers = df2[(df2["supplier in ocr"] != "") & (df2["supplier keywords"] != "")] 

percentilesupplierkeyword = len(supplier_filtered_df)/len(total_suppliers) * 100 

print(percentilesupplierkeyword,"% of supplier-keywords have an issue")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the script you have tried so far, as well as a sample DataFrame and the expected output?

Comment: you might want to make a selection with [pd.notnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notnull.html)

Comment: @DerekO Sure. 

Unfortunately I cant provide the whole script but Ill write the relevant parts. 
```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(supplier_data_df, columns=['supplier keywords', 'supplier in ocr'])

total_suppliers = df2[(df2["supplier in ocr"] != "") & (df2["supplier keywords"] != "")]

percentilesupplierkeyword = len(supplier_filtered_df)/len(total_suppliers) * 100

print(percentilesupplierkeyword,"% of supplier-keywords have an issue")
```

Comment: @MrFuppes Thank you but then I get the output that total_suppliers is equal to zero which leads to a division by zero. Not sure why it says that its value is zero though.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're doing good.
You can either consider dropping the NaN values or excluding them from your dataframe and then perform your following computations.

If you want to drop the NaN values

```
df2.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Or you could use the fillna method to fill the nan values with 0.

```
df2.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

If you want to get the index list of the nan values

```
df2[df2["col1"].isna()].index.tolist()
```